# Redirect Subfolder of one domain to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdirectory

I have two domains, domain1.com and domain2.com. I want to redirect domain1.com/subfolder to domain2.com.

I know this can be done with .htaccess using: Redirect 301 /subfolder/ http://domain2.com/, putting the .htaccess file in the root of domain1.com. The problem I'm facing is to redirect without changing the addressbar. Is this possible?

domain1.com is running IIS and domain2.com is running Apache.

One solution I have come across is to put an iFrame in domain1.com/subfolder/index.html but this makes the address bar static.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a reverse proxy on the IIS server hosting **domain1.com**, [here's a link that shows you how to do that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx.)